# dynamic property call

Tags: php

is there a shorter way to achieve the following:

```
$i = 1;
$prop = 'image' . $i;
$image = $this->getObject->$prop;
```

I have in mind there was something like

```
$image = $this->getObject->image{$i};
```

any ideas?

Comment: read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
$this->getObject->{'image'.$i};
```

Comment: i think this is not a shortcut

Comment: works like a charm. have you got an idea to achieve the same, but with an method?

Comment: @Flask: You mean accessing the method of an object? It works the same way, you just need to add the parenthesis to call the method. But then `call_user_func` as @diEcho proposed might be better.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to make an array of all images, and then call it like this:

```
$this->getObject->image[$i]
```

This will be faster, and is often much easier to work with than a bunch of different variables.